# Geodata farm plugin error

Tags: qgis-plugins, error, qgis-3

When i try to start GeoDataFarm Plugin in QGIS i get this error :

"2018-11-26T08:32:18     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/robert.banjad/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\geodatafarm\GeoDataFarm.py", line 41, in 
              import reportlab
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 665, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
             ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab'

```
         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 337, in startPlugin
          plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/Users/robert.banjad/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\geodatafarm\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
          from .GeoDataFarm import GeoDataFarm
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 665, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/robert.banjad/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\geodatafarm\GeoDataFarm.py", line 53, in 
          import reportlab
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 665, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
         ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab'
         " and it cannot be loaded, anyone know why?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to error message, you need addition python library [reportlab](https://pypi.org/project/reportlab/).
Just install required dependencies via following command:

```
pip install reportlab
```

Also check that you install this python library in right python in your system. It must be python used by QGIS.